# Excel - VBA Loop through list output current list item only

Tags: excel

I have a list I have populated on one worksheet, I have code that loops through the list in order to populate the parameter of a linked data table on another worksheet.

I have everything working except being able to output the single row from the list it is currently working on to a cell on another worksheet.

This is driving me mad, thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Where is the code  ?

Answer (score 1):

If your are working with a `For` loop you can use the "`i`" variable to locate the row. The build of the cell reference regarding workbook/worksheet goes:

```
Workbook.Worksheet.Cells(row, Column).Value

`wb.ws2.Cells(i, 3).Valuews2.Cells(i, 3).Value` '(i didn't define workbook since in my example I working with the same workbook/excel file)
```

Some logical explanation with example code:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set your worksheet name to copy from
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Set your worksheet name to copy to
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Column A

For i = 1 To lrow ' Loop from row 1 to lastrow
    ws2.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value 'Print out the current value you are working with.. (copy from sheet 1, Column A to sheet 2, column C)
    ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value = i 'Print out in Column B in sheet2, the current value "i" is
Next i
End Sub
```

Result,

Copy from sheet1:

[image]

Copy to sheet2:

where column B is the `ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value = i`,

where column C is the `ws2.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value`

[image]

Happy coding :)!

Answer (score 0):

Before the `For` loop, import a `With` statement with the sheet name of the sheet you want to use. Then, after the `For` loop, close the `With` statement. Using this approach, you don't need to repeatedly reference the sheet in each line of code; you only reference sheets not included in the `With` statement. For example:

```
With Sheet1 `<= The sheet name or variable

   For i=1 to 100
      .range("A" & i).value '<= I only use ".Range" without the sheet name in front to refer to Sheet1 (the one in the with statement).
      Sheet2.range("A" & i).value '<= A reference to another sheet (i.e. not the one in the with statement).
   Next i

end With
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is that OP is trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Probably OP output the result to a different worksheet:
I have everything working except being able to output the single row from the list it is currently working on to a cell on another worksheet.

Comment: @ImranMalek, OP is trying to copy or place a value from one sheet to another, and is probably struggling since he doesn't set variables that links to each worksheet. When you work on only one worksheet you don't need to think about to "declare" which worksheet you are working at. But when you are working across worksheet, that's is essential :)

Comment: Sorry, to explain. The process is thus; 1. loop through list on sheet a, 2. copy the single current value from the list to a single set cell on sheet b to open another workbook 3. use the value on sheet b as a parameter for a linked data table which then produces a report. I have 50 clients which at month end I run a generic template for, just looking to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've found the answer (typical now I've created the thread).

```
> Dim aCell As Range Dim lastRow As Long lastRow =
> ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row For Each aCell In
> Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Cells
> 
> aCell.Copy Sheets("lookups").Range("y3")
```

Thanks for all your comments anyway.